# Android: ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER without cropping image?

Tags: android, android-intent, crop, wallpaper

select wallpaper code below

```
Intent pickWallpaper = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(pickWallpaper,"Select Wallpaper"));
```

but the wallpaper get cropped like this picture

[image]

i need to set the wallpaper fit the screen size without cropping/reserve for another page

how to make the wallpaper picker select one page wallpaper only?